# DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I have a custom component that extends WindowedApplication and a spark skin to go with it. In the skin I have an HGroup, and I would like the x position of the HGroup to be set to the right edge of the window's title. My problem is that every time I try to bind the x of the Hgroup, FlashBuilder tells me that the databinding will not be able to detect the assignemnts. Below are some of the different methods I've tried and what exactly FlashBuilder has told me:

```
<s:HGroup x= "{hostComponent.titleBar.titleText.right as Number}">
```

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "right".

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "titleBar".

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "titleText".

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var _offset:Object;

        public function get offset():Object{
            return _offset;
        }

        public function set offset(value:Object):void{
            _offset = value;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Binding source="hostComponent.titleBar.titleText.right" destination="offset"/>

<s:HGroup x= "{offset as Number}">
```

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "offset".

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "right".

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "titleBar".

DataBindings will not be able to detect assignments to "titleText".

I'm fairly new to flex, so sorry if there is an obvious answer that I missed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify - is it not working as you'd like, or are you simply looking to deal with the warnings?

Answer (score 1):

1- verify that  your skin host component is setted correctly : `[HostComponent("YourComponent")]`

2- create a global bindable number var and set it's value to  `titleBar.titleText.right`
   something like this :

```
[Bindable]public var textRightPos:Number = titleBar.titleText.right;
```

3- if the probleme persiste you can try to set your HGroup x value on a creationcomplete event handler 
   of your skin.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippent that you've provided add a metadata tag **[Bindable]** before '_offset'.

It should be like this:

```
[Bindable]
private var _offset:Object;
```

after this change, you'll not see any warning and databinding should work.
Also i would advice setting some default value to _offset.